# How to average the selected values

Tags: javascript, arrays

New to JavaScript so any help would be appreciated!
I have a table in php that pulls from the DB and puts that info into a table. I have two sets of checkboxes that I can check and it will display the values in an alert window.

Table:

```
<table class="table mt-4 table table-striped" id="suppTable">
    <thead>
        <th scope="col">Avg Entry</th>
        <th scope="col">Avg Highest</th>
        <th scope="col">Entry</th>
        <th scope="col">Highest</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($supp as $supp)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="entry" value="{{ $supp->entry}}" name="rows[]"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="highest" value="{{$supp->highest}}" name="rows[]"></td>
                <td><span style="color: gray">{{$supp->system->name}}</span></td>
                <td><span style="color: #007E33">{{$supp->entry}} </span></td>
                <td><span style="color: #007E33">{{$supp->highest}} </span></td>
                <td><span style="color: #007E33">{{$supp->days}} </span></td>
                <td><span style="color: gray">{{$supp->employed  }}</span></td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />
```

and my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(selected) {
        return selected.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / selected.length;
    }

    function GetSelected() {
        //Create an Array.
        var selected = new Array();

        //Reference the Table.
        var suppTable = document.getElementById("suppTable");

        //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
        var entry = suppTable.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

        // Loop and push the checked CheckBox value in Array.
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

            if (entry[i].checked) {
                selected.push(entry[i].value);
            }
        }

        alert("Average: " + calculate(selected));
    }
</script>
```

It works fine and pops up the alert with the values checked.
But it shows the values like: 10002000 (not sure why) when it is suppose to be averaging 1000 and 2000 and only show 1500 (which is the average of 3000
Any ideas or point in the right direction?

Comment: Collect the sum and count in the loop where you collect the values?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". I don't see anything that displays the average you've calculated.

Comment: I tried using parseInt, thinking maybe it would work, but it only returns 2000 no matter what is checked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the same answer. I changed my function to the below and it is now averaging what is checked as long as it has a value.

```
function calculate(selected) 
{
    return selected.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)) / selected.length;
}
```